# Return a value from sequelize query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm new to sequelize. I'm using mysql as my database. I've a sequelize query which finds the email-id from the database. By using the result of this query, I got the ID of that row. Now I need to return this value. Can someone please help me how to do that.

Here is my code.

```
var userId = getUserId(email_address);
function getUserId(email_address) {
   models.users.findOne({
     where: {
       email: email_address
     }
   }).then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        var applicantId = result.id;
        return applicantId;  // This is what I need to do
      } else {
        console.log("Could not find Email");
      }
   });
}
```

Here I need to return the variable applicantId to the calling function.

Comment: First of, you can't just return the value. The db query is an asynchronous call and needs to be handled as that. Your function getUserId() needs to return a Promise. Just return models.users.findOne() method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Himmet. when I return models.users.findOne() I will get a promise object at userId. How to access the value from that promise object? Can you please help me out.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to use javascript promises http://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-promises/ i suggest you start there.

Comment: Thank you @GrimurD. That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sequelize call to the database is asynchronous so you need to alter your code a bit to work with promises. Something like this:

```
function getUserId(email_address) {
   return models.users.findOne({
     where: {
       email: email_address
     }
   });
}

getUserId("some@email.com").then(function(result){
   console.log(result.id);
});
```

check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpvjxvky/) that mocks your scenario

Comment: Thank You @scottjustin5000. This worked. I Was bit confused with promises.