# Sequelize: how to return a specific value from a field

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, backend, dbeaver

[image] Hi everyone! I'm new to databases, sequelize and other stuff but I'm trying to learn!
I have this table called "Posts"
and I have like 3 fake migrations

What I want is to have back only a value.
I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954637/return-a-value-from-sequelize-query) but it doesn't really help me...
So if I want "ipsum" I can write this SQL in DBeaver: `select * from "posts" where "type"='ipsum'`. And it works.
But I need to do the same in Sequelize.
I tried

```
export const loadNewPost = async (components) => {
  try {
    const newPost = await components.db.Posts.findAll({
      where: {
        type: "ipsum",
      },
    });
    return newPost;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};
```

But it doesn't work!
(then I should place this function into an endpoint, but this is another story!)
Any help would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful with the comma, in this case
“ type: "ipsum",  “
Becomes:
“ type: "ipsum"  “